# Scroll to top of datatable in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, datatables

I am trying to add a function to my `DataTables` that scrolls to the top of the table when the pagination links are clicked and I have followed the guide here:

http://jsfiddle.net/EjbEJ/

```
function paginateScroll() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".dataTables_wrapper").offset().top
  }, 100);
  console.log('pagination button clicked');
  $(".paginate_button").unbind('click', paginateScroll);
  $(".paginate_button").bind('click', paginateScroll);
}
paginateScroll();
```

This works perfectly but unfortunately the page I have the `DataTable` on is loading in to an iframe and in an iframe it no longer works. Any idea how to get this script working in an iframe?

Answer (score 0):

yes you must use postMessage to communicate with the iframe, and likely have your code in both places, so the parent frame can send a message to the frame, and then the frame can do the scroll animation.

https://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage

Answer (score 0):

just to let you know I resolved this issue. I just needed to add $(parent.document).find to get the html and body tags of the parent frame.

```
function paginateScroll() {
  $(parent.document).find('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".dataTables_wrapper").offset().top
  }, 100);
  //console.log('pagination button clicked');
  $(".paginate_button").unbind('click', paginateScroll);
  $(".paginate_button").bind('click', paginateScroll);
}
paginateScroll();
```

Cheers